# Poner una imagen al lado de la otra

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap, responsive, ccs

disculpen es que tengo varias imagenes que estoy intentando centrar y poner una al lado de la otra, pero llevo como 3-4 horas viendo tutoriales videos, de flex, grids, con bootstrap los col, y siempre me queda uno debajo de otro.
no se si tengo un error o algo mal...pondre todo el style en un solo archivo para que vean todo el codigo. en donde quedo vacio el class="" alli ponia los col- y las cosas q iban pasando en los tutoriales, pero ninguno me funcionaba.

Lo que quiero hacer, es que en pantallas pequeñas como celulares, se vean 2 imagenes(una al lado de la otra) y ya si la pantalla es grande, que se vean de 3 en 3.

CELL:

2-2

2-2

COMPU:

3-3-3

3-3-3

DE ANTE MANO MUCHAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 0):

Con Boostrap es fácil, he hecho lo que pide poniendo las siguientes clases. Igual te recomiendo que leas o tomes algunos cursos de BS en YouTube :-)

```
<div class="float-left mr-1 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <a href="#.html"> TITULO 1<br><img src="https://thedesignangel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/300-90x90-copy.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <style>
      /*Para el footer*/
      .wgfooter{
      width: 100% !important;
      height: 200px;
      }
      /*Fuentes*/
      @font-face {
      font-family: burbank1;
      src: url("./inicioG_files/Burbank1.woff") format('woff');
      font-weight: 700;
      font-style: normal;
      }
      @font-face {
      font-family: burbank2;
      src: url("./inicioG_files/Burbank2.woff") format('woff');
      font-weight: 700;
      font-style: normal;
      }
      @font-face {
      font-family: burbank3;
      src: url("./inicioG_files/Burbank3.woff") format('woff');
      font-weight: 700;
      font-style: normal;
      }
      body,html {
      font-family: burbank2;
      text-align: center;
      }
      a,p{
          text-align: center;
      }
      .titulo {
      font-family: burbank1;
      }
      /*CCS BODY*/
      article{
      text-align: center;
      }
      img{
      text-align: center;
      width: 200px;
      height: 280px;
      }

   </style>
   <body>
      <header class="titulo">
         <a href="#">WEB/</a>
      </header>
      <!--script para anuncio1-->
      <div id="divPadre">
         <!--script-body-->
      </div>
      <br>
      <div>
         <p>
            <a href="#">FREE FIRE</a>
         </p>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="float-left mr-1 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
               <a href="#.html"> TITULO 1<br><img src="https://thedesignangel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/300-90x90-copy.jpg" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left mr-1 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
               <a href="#"> TITULO 2<br><img src="https://thedesignangel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/300-90x90-copy.jpg" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left mr-1 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
               <a href="#"> TITULO 3<br><img src="https://thedesignangel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/300-90x90-copy.jpg" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left mr-1 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
               <a href="#"> TITULO 4<br><img src="https://thedesignangel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/300-90x90-copy.jpg" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left mr-1 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
               <a href="#"> TITULO 5<br><img src="https://thedesignangel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/300-90x90-copy.jpg" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left mr-1 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
               <a href="#"> TITULO 6<br><img src="https://thedesignangel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/300-90x90-copy.jpg" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left mr-1 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
               <a href="#"> TITULO 7<br><img src="https://thedesignangel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/300-90x90-copy.jpg" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left mr-1 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
               <a href="#"> TITULO 8<br><img src="https://thedesignangel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/300-90x90-copy.jpg" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left mr-1 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
               <a href="#"> TITULO 9<br><img src="https://thedesignangel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/300-90x90-copy.jpg" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left mr-1 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
               <a href="#"> TITULO 10<br><img src="https://thedesignangel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/300-90x90-copy.jpg" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left mr-1 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
               <a href="#"> TITULO 11<br><img src="https://thedesignangel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/300-90x90-copy.jpg" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left mr-1 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
               <a href="#"> TITULO 12<br><img src="https://thedesignangel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/300-90x90-copy.jpg" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, en un par de horas verificare y hare como me dices

Answer (score 0):

tenias el problema en tu codigo que en la etiqueta `<div>` correspondiente a la clase `class="row"` te faltaba el igual, por eso no se te aplicaban los estilos.

Para lo que quieres hacer, debes usar en cada etiqueta correspondiente al hijo directo del row la clase `class="col-md-4"` para las pantallas grandes y `class="col-sm-6"` para pantallas pequeñas. Esos numeros se deben a que el grid de bootstrap tiene 12 numeros, si coges el 4 significa que estas repartiendo el contenido en un espacio de 4 para el primero, 4 para el segundo y 4 para el tercero, sumando doce. Por otra parte, si coges 6 estarias cogiendo 6 para el primero y 6 para el segundo, sumando igualmente 12.

El codigo que te propongo es el siguiente:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="https://WEB//.html"> TITULO<br><img src="./inicioG_files/f1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
       </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Deberas de ponerle ese nombre de clase a todos los divs que tenias con la etiqueta `class=""` vacios.

PD: He visto tu css y no estas teniendo en cuenta una cosa muy importante al usar bootstrap. Siempre que quieras aplicar un estilo css a una atributo en el cual tambien estes usando bootstrap deberas añadirle el parametro `!important`, imaginate un width deberia de quedar asi: `width: 200px !important` ya que el bootstrap se superpone a lo que hagas con css.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda. Un saludo

Comment: muchas gracias, en un par de horas verificare y hare como me dices